# Where to put `componentWillMount` initialisation function that modifies state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Since `componentWillMount` will be deprecated, I would like to know the recommended way of handling init functions that modify state. I'm aware the general approach regarding `componentWillMount` is to move things into either the constructor or `componentDidMount`, but there are problems with both in this case.

Connect Four example code (non-essential code left out):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rows: 6, // # rows of the grid; cols = rows + 1
      grid: [],
      fullColumns: [],
      // ...
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.initGrid(this.state.rows);
  }

  initGrid(rows) {
    // Create grid data structure to keep track of which grid cells
    // contain checkers of which color:
    // 'grid' = array of COLUMN arrays!
    let grid = [];
    // Create the 'fullColumns' array to keep track of which grid columns are full:
    let fullColumns = [];
    let cols = rows + 1;
    for (let c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      fullColumns.push(false);
      let column = [];
      for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        column.push(null);
      }
      grid.push(column);
    }

    this.setState({
      rows,
      grid,
      fullColumns,
    });
  }

  // ...

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I cannot put the `this.initGrid` function in `componentDidMount` because `this.state.grid` needs to be initialised in order to mount the component.
Neither can this function be called in the constructor, because it makes use of `setState`. The `initGrid` function is also used in other parts of the codebase, so it still needs `setState` in order to function there.

Am I missing something obvious? What is the professional way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been thinking about this problem for a while, and come up with several solutions, all of which have their own trade-offs. I'll document them here so they may still be useful for others coming upon this problem. Pick the solution that best matches your project's needs:

- Create a duplicate `initGrid` function intended for use in the constructor alone (assigning directly to `this.state` instead of using `setState`). Apart from the code duplication and clear violation of DRY, this also creates an extra *'single-use'* method that results in the "Do not mutate state directly, Use setState()" warning, which is rather annoying.
- Use an anonymous self-invoking function that assigns directly to `this.state.grid` and `this.state.fullColumns` in the constructor:

  ```
  constructor(props) {
    // ...

    [this.state.grid, this.state.fullColumns] = (function(rows) {
      let grid = [];
      let fullColumns = [];
      let cols = rows + 1;
      for (let c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
        fullColumns.push(false);
        let column = [];
        for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
          column.push(null);
        }
        grid.push(column);
      }
      return [grid, fullColumns];
    })(this.state.rows);
  }
  ```

  `componentWillMount` can now be deleted. This also gets rid of the "Do not mutate state directly, Use setState()" warning, and does not pointlessly create another method for single use. **But** it still unnecessarily duplicates code from `this.initGrid`.
- Simply hardcode the initial grid and fullColumns arrays in state:

  ```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rows: 6,
      grid: [
              [null, null, null, null, null, null],
              [null, null, null, null, null, null],
              [null, null, null, null, null, null],
              [null, null, null, null, null, null],
              [null, null, null, null, null, null],
              [null, null, null, null, null, null],
              [null, null, null, null, null, null],
            ],
      fullColumns: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
    }
  }
  ```

  `componentWillMount` can now be deleted. This does sacrifice customizability and feels rather unprofessional. However, it is not without its own advantages; it results in less logic, is more efficient, and also helps in visualising/documenting the code.
- Modify the `initGrid` function to differentiate between calling it from the constructor vs calling it from elsewhere:

  ```
  initGrid(rows) {
    // Create grid data structure to keep track of which grid cells
    // contain checkers of which color:
    // 'grid' = array of COLUMN arrays!
    let cols = rows + 1;
    let grid = [];
    let fullColumns = [];
    for (let c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      fullColumns.push(false);
      let column = [];
      for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        column.push(null);
      }
      grid.push(column);
    }

    // If 'this.state.grid' is already initialised (i.e. non-empty),
    // the call is NOT from inside the constructor:
    if (this.state.grid.length !== 0) {
      this.setState({
        rows,
        grid,
        fullColumns,
      });
    } else {
      // If the grid is empty, this call came from inside the constructor,
      // so we disable the "Do not mutate state directly, Use setState()" warning:
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-direct-mutation-state
      this.state = {
        ...this.state,
        grid,
        fullColumns,
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  This does not unnecessarily duplicate code, and still keeps the customizability. It still has the "Do not mutate state directly, Use setState()" warning, but it is silenced with the `// eslint-...` comment. Now we can call `this.initGrid(this.state.rows)` in the constructor instead of in `componentWillMount`.

  This feels like the **most professional solution** to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can have it in the constructor, just replace

```
this.setState({
      rows,
      grid,
      fullColumns
    });
```

with

```
this.state = {
   ...this.state
   rows,
   grid,
   fullColumns
}
```

---

You can also move `initGrid` to `componentDidMount` method, by rendering `null` when the component state is not fully initialized or providing meaningful defaults.

```
render() {
   if(this.state.grid) {
      return ...
   }
   else {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that `this.initGrid` is also used by other functions that do need `setState`. So this would mean I need to create a duplicate function with just the stateSetting done differently ...

Comment: Plus that would also generate the "Do not mutate state directly, Use setState()" warning, which is rather annoying.

Comment: Why not do the calculations in the constructor and initialize the state with the values? Can't say more without knowing how this is supposed to be used, but if it's a one-time calculation of something, might as well do it there. You're passing in  a value of 6 which you initialize in the constructor also

Comment: Yeah, that's not a bad idea. I've thought of this too, but it's not really a one time thing (the gridsize can be changed by the user, which uses the `initGrid` function). So it's still possible, but it bothers me that the code would then be duplicated; once in `initGrid`, and once in the constructor.

Comment: Is there a fix for the "Do not mutate state directly, Use setState()" warning, when you intend to only use the function that mutates state directly inside the constructor?

Comment: You can silence it with `// eslint-disable-next-line react/no-direct-mutation-state`

Answer (score 0):

`initGrid` doesn't need to be a part of the component at all, it isn't tied to a state except that it tries to update it.

It can be a helper function and used where needed:

```
function initGrid(rows) {
    ...
    return {
      rows,
      grid,
      fullColumns,
    };
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = initGrid(6);
  ...
}
```

Comment: `initGrid` is actually used in other parts of the codebase, so it requires `setState` and can't be isolated from the component.

Comment: I missed the comment. Nothing in the answer contradicts this. If you need to reuse initGrid elsewhere, reuse it. The idea is to decouple state logic from setState because this results in design flaws. initGrid that uses setState cannot be reused in other components without inheritance and cannot be used in getDerivedStateFromProps in same component. If you need to use it together with setState, it's `setState(({ rows }) => initGrid(rows))`. `initGrid` signature could be modified for convenience to be used like updater function, `setState(initGrid)`.